# if (Context.Items["ml"].ToString() == null) error

Tags: asp.net

I am having trouble with my code. I don't know why it is throwing errors.

This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlDataAdapter da;
    string con = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BanHang;Integrated Security=True";

    if (Context.Items["ml"].ToString() == null)
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select *from mathang", con);
    else
    {
        string ml = Context.Items["ml"].ToString();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select *from mathang where maloai = '" + ml + "'", con);
    }

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    this.DataList2.DataSource = dt;
    this.DataList2.DataBind();                
}
```

These are the errors:

> Line 17: string con = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BanHang;Integrated Security=True";
>   Line 18:
>   **Line 19: if (Context.Items["ml"].ToString() == null)**
>   Line 20: da = new SqlDataAdapter("select *from mathang", con);
>   Line 21: else
>   Source File: D:\Th0an\HocTap\ASP.NET\BaiHoc\BaiTap4\BaiTap4\MatHang.aspx.cs

Comment: what is the data source you are trying to access? where do you have that database?

Answer (score 2):

`Context.Items[]` returns an Object. If the item with key "ml" is missing from the `Items` collection, it will return a null object. If you attempt to use 
`ToString()` on a null object you will get a `NullReferenceException`.